# Google Classroom Grade book API code var. string

Tags: google-classroom

In google classroom API code, how do i find the overall grade (percentage) data point that is assigned in grades manipulated by the weighted grade categories?

Comment: Hi, would you consider accepting and/or upvoting my answer? That's useful since StackOverflow relies on this to share knowledge other users.

Answer (score 0):

#### Grade categories:

Unfortunately, the API doesn't currently support grade categories. This functionality has already been requested in Issue Tracker:

- [Feature Request: Include Grade Category field in Coursework Resource](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123557207)

Anyone interested in this functionality can click the star on the top-left of the referenced page in order to keep track of its development and to prioritize its implementation.

#### Non-weighted:

Overall grades can currently be retrieved as long as there are no weighted grade categories: just sum up `assignedGrade` for each [studentSubmission](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions) for each specific student (that is, the total amount of points a  student has earned), and divide the calculated value by the total amount of `maxPoints` for each [courseWork](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork) in the course (that is, maximum possible amount of points in a class).